# Как использовать foreach внутри file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Как использовать foreach внутри file_get_contents.
Например это:

```
foreach (explode(', ',$rowh['tag']) as $key) {$tag = "#".$key;}
$title = "".$name."\n".$tag";
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chat_id."&photo=".$photo."&caption=".urlencode($title)."&parse_mode=html");
```

В отдельном они работает но не показывает теги. Если вставить функция foreach внутри file_get_contents код вообще не работает. В результате нужно показывать как это: пример:

```
 Зимние кроссовки: #krosovki #zimnie #krosovkizimnie
```

Пожалуйста помогите. Спасибо заражение.

Comment: у Вас там ошибка, Вы постоянно заменяете переменную $tag. Сделайте: `$tag.= "#".$key." ";` И перед foreach вставьте `$tag="";` если вдруг тегов не будет, чтобы не было ошибки.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Заработала. Но теперь есть один неудобство. В базу данных колонка **tag** ест теги с пробелами. например: **privet** , **kak delo** , **xorowo**. В этом случае код показывает **#privet** , **#kak delo** (это не будет тег) и **#xorowo**. Как удалит пробел между словами.

Comment: `$tag.= "#".str_replace(" ","",$key)." ";`

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБОООООООООООООООООООООООООООО. ЗАРАБОТАЛА

Comment: вот как люди должны понимать такие теги?